# Python3: c-type segfault from multithreaded C shared library

Tags: python, c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

I've looked at other StackOverflow related questions and answers and followed the information given. I am still having trouble.

Running Python3 on Linux which accesses a shared C library (.so). The C library will spin up threads as needed. I am having as issue with segmentation faults when accessing a C API while threads are running. The issue appears only if the C thread calls a callback function within Python. If the C thread runs without calling the callback, there are no issues. In the code below, the Python lines `print(GetData(128))` will get the string and print it to the console before causing a segfault. Again, I only get a segfault on `GetData` if the thread is running AND calls the event or callback. Other `C` APIs which return a `char*`, but take no parameters, work just fine with the thread running.

Python:

```
# Within a class, but not shown for simplicity.
EVENT = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_int)
lib = CDLL("library.so")
lib.GetData.restype = c_uint
lib.GetData.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_uint]
lib.SetEvent.argtypes = [EVENT]

def GetData(count):
    buf = create_string_buffer(count)
    lib.GetData(buf, count)
    return buf.value.decode("utf-8")

def SetEvent(ev):
    lib.SetEvent(ev)

# Code outside of class.
def Event(e):
    print("Event " + str(e))
    if e == 2:
        print(GetData(128)) # Event works fine until I call this.

SetEvent(EVENT(Event))

cnt = 0
while cnt < 10:
    print(GetData(128)) # Works if I do not call SetEvent.
    cnt = cnt + 1
    sleep(1)
```

C/C++ Code:

```
typedef void(*Event)(int i);
Event efunc = nullptr;

static void ThreadFunc()
{
    int i = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        if (efunc != nullptr) { efunc(++i); } // Raise event.

        if (i > 10) { i = 0; }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

extern "C" unsigned int GetData(char* data, unsigned int count)
{
    const char* str = "Random data for testing";
    std::strcpy(data, str);
    return std::strlen(str);
}

extern "C" void SetEvent(Event e)
{
    efunc = e;

    if (efunc != nullptr) { myThread = std::thread(ThreadFunc); }
}
```

I've put the simple versions of the code above to make the problem easier to understand. I am aware there is missing error checking and the thread runs forever. This isn't the case in the actual code, but this post would be too long if I added everything. Also, the `C` library needs to create threads, this can't change. The same `C` library works when dynamically loaded and run with `C++` and `C#`.

### Update

I've added the Python library to the C/C++ shared library and made the following code changes (see above for reference).

C/C++:

```
static void ThreadFunc()
{
    int i = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        if (efunc != nullptr)
        {
            PyGILState_STATE state = PyGILState_Ensure();
            // Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
            efunc(++i); // Raise event.
            // Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
            PyGILState_Release(state);
        }

        if (i > 10) { i = 0; }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

extern "C" void SetEvent(Event e)
{
    efunc = e;

    if (efunc != nullptr)
    {
        if (!PyEval_ThreadsInitialized())
        {
            PyEval_InitThreads();
        }

        myThread = std::thread(ThreadFunc)
    }
}
```

Things work until the Python callback runs `print(GetData(128))`, after this each callback to the Python code prints `SystemError: null argument to internal routine` to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the code works fine in C++ and C#, it's likely that Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) is contributing to the issue.One way to work around this issue is by acquiring the GIL within the C code before invoking the Python callback, and then releasing it afterwards. In the Python C API, this can be done using PyGILState_Ensure and PyGILState_Release.

If you don't want to modify your C/C++ library, another workaround would be to use Python's ctypes library to manually acquire and release the GIL within Python before and after calling the callback.

Comment: I'm new to Python, could you elaborate more on using Python's ctypes library to manually acquire and release the GIL? I cannot change the C/C++ library.

Comment: maybe it would be better to write a wrapper around it, it would be easier and more cleaner look into https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads

Comment: I added the `PyGILState_STATE state = PyGILState_Ensure();` and corresponding code to the C/C++ library. I know get `SystemError: null argument to internal routine` after the callback.

Comment: I've added an "Update" section to my post.